# how to write alert with different font color in java script pop up

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, ajax

- i want to show a pop up with red color for some words
- i want to show variable "keyword name" in red color as well as "
  Todays Position" word . These both words should be in red color font.

  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "clentscript", "alert('Kindly Enter Todays Position for " + KeywordName + " to Update keyword Target date... ');", true);

Comment: Google for "Bootstrap modal dialog".

Comment: You'll need something better than `prompt`.  Think about building a simple modal - a `div` absolutely positioned center-screen with a nice drop-shadow works well

Comment: im using visual studio 2008 and my framework is 3.5 i cannot use modern things here.@connexo

Comment: The .NET or VS version has absolutely nothing to do with HTML & CSS. So you can still use "modern" markup/styling.

Comment: i want to show the pop up in back end code . i cant show pop in front end aspx@mboldt

Comment: like this  if (CurrentPos == "")
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "clentscript", "alert('Kindly Enter Todays Position for " + KeywordName + " to Update keyword Target date... ');", true);
                }